# Tapestry Security With Tynamo - Getting Started

Tags: java, tapestry, tynamo

I'm currently working on implementing security measurements for some Tapestry 5 projects. Now I've come across Tynamo Tapestry Security and it seems to be doing a really good job on authorization, but actually there also does not seem to be too much information on how to get started. Does anybody know some sources other than the offical Tynamo site? Or maybe some code examples etc.?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Apache Tynamo Guide](http://tynamo.org/tapestry-security+guide)
2. [Apache Shiro Documentation](http://shiro.apache.org/documentation.html)

What else would you need ? If you don't understand the tapestry related code, then you may need to read this:

1. [Introduction to tapestry IoC](http://tapestry.apache.org/ioc.html)
2. [Defining Tapestry IOC Services](http://tapestry.apache.org/defining-tapestry-ioc-services.html)
3. [Tapestry IoC Configuration](http://tapestry.apache.org/tapestry-ioc-configuration.html)
4. [Symbols](http://tapestry.apache.org/symbols.html)

**1** is an introduction to **2, 3 & 4**. There are many other chapters to read about in Tapestry's IoC but I suggest those as a start to cover most of what you may need to understand and use Tapestry's IoC.

Comment: I've read all of the above sources already... and I do have an understanding of Tapestry IoC and Services.  For me the tynamo guide does not seem to provide enough information. I have for example no idea on how and where to configure a realm. I'm really sorry if i maybe just miss something really important or whatever... but I'm really kind of stuck.

Comment: Have you read `Apache Shiro`'s documentation ? Configuring a realm is an `Apache Shiro` matter, not tapestry.

Comment: Yes, it took me a while to figure out, but finally it's "working" ... I'm not finished yet, but I think I managed the hardest part. Thanks though!